# How does Achille Varzi’s metaphysics avoid collapsing into Mark Heller’s Eliminativism

Tags: metaphysics, objects, constructivism

Achille Varzi is apparently a conventionalist about all kinds, natural and artifactual while being a mereological universalist who has a pretty permissive ontology. What keeps his position from collapsing into Mark Heller’s 4-D hunk of matter view, where all the objects we take to exist are actually just conventional and only hunks of matter exist.

Anyone familiar enough with them to clear this up?